# Remove calendar popupup from row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem in removing my calender from the text box

What am doing is i will set the date value automatically and i dont want to allow anybody to edit it any more

Here is my row

```
<td class="ItemDetailValue">
 <input type="text" 
 name="flexFields(fild2659)" 
 size="14" value=""   
 class="inputfield cal-icon" 
 id="artifactField_fild2659" 
 autocomplete="off" 
 style="background-color: rgb(255, 182, 193);">&nbsp;<img class="calendar" 
 for="artifactField_fild2659" src="/sf-images/icons/date_popup.png" 
 align="absmiddle" 
 width="16" 
 height="16" 
 alt="Select Date" 
 onclick="return calShow('artifactField_fild2659');">

 <span class="artifactFieldError" id="err_fild2659"></span>
</td>
```

I tried with many things still the pop is clickable

```
jQuery(".calendar").css('display', 'none');
jQuery(".calendar").removeAttr("onclick");
```

and even removed the img src still no luck

Please throw some light on this

Comment: Create jsfiddle.net for same

Comment: Try using the web developer to turn off and/or delete stuff one at a time until you see the calendar go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readonly` on the input element or Try disabling it like this

```
$(function(){
   $("input").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

**EDIT:**

Try using the `readonly` attribute on the input use `event.preventDefault();`

```
$('#artifactField_fild2659').click(function(){
 event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: He has used onclick on the input which will open the calendar.

Comment: Then you need to add $("#artifactField_fild2659").off('click') and it should work, or do i oversee something?

Comment: Problem with diable attribute it wont send the values in submit i need the value to be sent on submit

Comment: see the edit,I have one question though, if you are setting the value by default, why do you need that `onclick` attribute?